# Use access_token from server in new iOS SSO client environment

Tags: ios, sdk, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm working on a service where we allow users to signup and login with their Facebook accounts. The service runs both on the web and on an iOS client.

The use case I'm having trouble with is this:

1. User has logged into iOS app with username / password.
2. User connects his/her Facebook profile to our service online.
3. User logs back into iOS app and wants to interact with GraphAPI.

At the last step - I'm not having any success - using the users access_token saved on the server with the facebook-ios-sdk. When doing the call for extendending life of access_token I get the following error.

- Error code: 10
- Error message: "The access token was not obtained using single sign-on"

Are server side access_token not compatible with the iOS SDK?

The reverse situation works like a charm:

1. User logs into iOS app with Facebook SSO
2. iOS app sends access_token to server.
3. Server does GraphAPI request with acces_token
4. Profit